# Iterating through SQL Data and then Posting Query Results into appropriate input fields

Tags: php, jquery, sql

What I'm trying to do here is I have 5 input fields, each has its own total weight for Lane-1,Lane-2,Poly-1,Poly-2,Poly-3 that will be displayed by what's in the database... I could do this with 5 different JS functions and 5 separate php files with SQL statements pertaining specifically to that lane type, but I'd rather do it all in one structure or one file and one JS function, if at all possible? Any ideas how I might go about this? I have it working for just the "else" part of the SQL statement, but I need to get the other data pertaining to the other lane types (lead-2, poly-1, etc...) Thanks in advance!

I can't even say I am doing any of this right, so feel free to chastise me.

HTML

```
<body onload="getLaneWeight();">
<form id="Warehouse_Worksheet" name="Warehouse_Worksheet">
<table align="center">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Lane Types
                </th>
                <th>
                    Total Weight
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Lead 1
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Lead-1" readonly="readonly" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Lead 2
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Lead-2" readonly="readonly" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Poly 1
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Poly-1" readonly="readonly" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Poly 2
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Poly-2" readonly="readonly" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Poly 3
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Poly-3" readonly="readonly" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
  </form>
  </body>
```

JS FILE

```
//Populate Lane Type Weight Table
function getLaneWeight() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: './php/getLaneWeight.php',
    data: 'lane_name=Lead-1',
    success: function (mydata) {
        document.forms['Warehouse_Worksheet'].elements['Lead-1'].value = mydata;
    },
    error: function () {

    },
    complete: function () {
        getLead2();//Call next Lane Type
    }
});
};
//Set Next Lane Weight
function getLead2() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: './php/getLaneWeight.php',
    data: 'lane_name=Lead-2',
    success: function (mydata) {
        document.forms['Warehouse_Worksheet'].elements['Lead-2'].value = mydata;
        //alert(document.forms['Warehouse_Worksheet'].elements['Lead-1'].value);
    },
    error: function () {

    },
    complete: function () {
        //getPoly1();//Call next Lane Type
    }
});
};
```

PHP/SQL

```
if(isset ($_GET['Poly-2'])){
    $sql="SELECT SUM(weight)
        FROM bundle_lanes
        WHERE lane_name = 'Poly-3'";
}else if(isset ($_GET['Poly-1'])){
    $sql="SELECT SUM(weight)
        FROM bundle_lanes
        WHERE lane_name = 'Poly-2'";
}else if(isset ($_GET['Lead-2'])){
    $sql="SELECT SUM(weight)
        FROM bundle_lanes
        WHERE lane_name = 'Poly-1'";
}else if(isset ($_GET['Lead-1'])){
    $sql="SELECT SUM(weight)
        FROM bundle_lanes
        WHERE lane_name = 'Lead-2'";
}else{
     $sql="SELECT SUM(weight)
        FROM bundle_lanes
        WHERE lane_name = 'Lead-1'";
}

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error'.mysql_error());

while ($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $weight = $data[0];
    echo $weight;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You than create a function like below

If your php code will definitely get the data you want than you can instantly insert it into the function below. If you want to store all 5 of them than use a for loop and array storing each of the names in php such as

```
   $myarray=('string1','string2');
   for($i=0;i<$myarray.length;i++){
       sqlQuery($myarray[i]);
   }
   function sqlQuery($lane_name){
       $sql
       $sql="SELECT SUM(weight)
         FROM bundle_lanes
         WHERE lane_name = '".$lane_name."'";
       $result=.......
       //check if data was stored.
       echo(<!-- new html code-->);
   }
```

This will store all 5 of the fields. If you only want 1 of them its better to use a switch case. If your php is in the same file than simply use php to generate the html using echo. You can insert variables that are set like this- echo("some text".$myvar."some more text");
If its a different file you'll need ajax in javascript to recieve the data and use a switch or if else case. For example

```
    if(response=='my response'){
    document.getElementById('my textbox').innerHTML(....);
    }
```

my javascript may not be accurate but i hope you get the idea

Comment: Yeh, I need to be able to have each input field display only the total weight of that lane type, so it's all separate according to the HTML. Is that what you're doing above? I don't see how I can pass that back to each input field value

Comment: i've edited my answer to help you. You'll need ajax if your php code is in a different file but if its in the same file than simply have the php to generate your html and use isset to add data to variables when it is posted.

Comment: Well, I am using ajax as you can see above, just not sure how to send and receive your data. Seems like you're giving me JS code. How will this work in a separate PHP file? My html, JS, and PHP files are all separate, so still trying to figure it out. Thanks so far for your help!

Comment: the first code is in php as stated while second is in js. the php will work in different files or same as you want, just use the echo for the response. For getting a response you'll have to search in ajax how as i'm not sure than execute a function to fill fields. You should simplify things by sending all data as a single string on the way back and catch that with ajax. There are many examples if you google search.

Comment: Well you opened up my eyes to the switch case statement, so now I'll go a different direction with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041139/passing-ajax-data-into-a-php-array-switch-case-to-process-sql-data Thanks!